# how to make a connection to datastore inside jstl tags

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, jstl, google-cloud-datastore

I'm making a project on Google App Engine and in one of my jsp files, I want to search an entry in my datastore. I normally do this search by clicking on a button on this jsp page, then I make the connection to datastore in a servlet and then I send the query results to jsp back . Well, I want to query datastore without clicking this button. When I load the page, I want to see the query results on my page. When I was using EL tag lib, I could do that by just typing <% %>, now I'm using jstl tag lib. So is there any way to do ? After using jstl tags, I'm not able to use EL tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Well, I want to query datastore without clicking this button*

Create a servlet which performs the job in `doGet()` method, forwards to a JSP which presents the result and just call the servlet's URL instead of the JSP's URL. It's exactly the same as you would do in a `doPost()` when a form was submitted, but then without the need to pass/collect request parameters.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - the 2nd Hello World example does exactly what you want.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, those `<% %>` things ("scriptlets") have definitely nothing to do with EL. EL is those `${}` things.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: I saw the example but I didn't understand one point. I have a hyperlink with a value. I want to make search according to this value in my datastore. How can I direct this hyperlink value to my servlet?

Comment: Just let the hyperlink point to servlet's URL as specified in `@WebServlet` or `web.xml`.

Comment: I did it like you said. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. The answer also clearly mentions that: *"just call the servlet's URL instead of the JSP's URL"*

Comment: By the way, I want to ask another question related to this topic. For instance, I want to forward response to another jsp file instead of the jsp file that contains my hyperlink. Is it possible?

Comment: Surely. Just change the path which you passed to `getRequestDispatcher()` method to the one of the desired JSP. Makes also completely sense, doesn't it? I'd invest some more time in learning basic HTTP / HTML / JSP / Servlet though.